How to calculate angle between vectors in a way that is invariant under translation?
Normally you just take the two vectors $\vec A $ and $\vec B $ and simply dot them, so $\vec A \cdot \vec B $ then divide by the product of there lengths and finally take the cosine inverse.
But this can't possibly be the full picture because if it was this calculation would produce exactly the same answer even if you add some vector $\vec X$ to both $\vec A $ and $\vec B $ in other words $(\vec A + \vec X) \cdot (\vec B + \vec X) $ should be equal to $\vec A \cdot \vec B $. But it's not .
I think i know what's wrong here, i thought i moved the origin of the entire vector space by simply adding $\vec X$ to everything, but i didn't actually do that, the vectors are still "attached" to the same old origin.
But this just begs the question, if this isn't how you calculate the angle between two vectors in a way that's invariant under vector space translation then what is?

the definition of angle between two vectors depends on where you put the origin. In a sense, to calculate the angle between two vectors you need 3 vectors.

So, vectors aren't really thought of as points in space, but as arrows from the origin. So translation should absolutely change the angle, as you are only moving the end points of the arrows, not where they originate from.

If you have vectors A, B and vector O that is your "origin" around which you compute the angle, then the angle is $\theta(A,B,O) = arccos( <A-O,B-O>/ ||A-O|| ||B-O||) $.
In this formulation, you get that it is invariant by translation of $A,B$ and $O$

@Exodd That is true. I should say that the more natural setting for that formulation would be affine spaces (i.e. vector spaces without origin).

@Exodd it certainly works, but it dosen't feel quite as elegent as it feels like it should be. I mean on a sheet of paper two people might disagree on where the origin might go but they certainly won't disagree on what the angle between two arbitrary arrows is. Is there no formulation that dosen't need to 'know' where the origin is?

If you have two arrows that start from a common point, then it is immediate to say that the common point is the origin

If you shift your vectors, you get new vectors: you should always look at them from the original point. The new vector will have a different angle between them. If you want to calculate the original angle (before the shift), you have to subtract your shift vector.

There are many things that can be called "vectors" in mathematics, so it's important to be clear about what kind of vector you mean when you ask about "vectors."
Some vectors do not make much geometric sense at all. But I assume you're talking about a geometric kind of vector.
If you're talking about a position vector, you are probably talking about a point in some Euclidean space of some number of dimensions (for example, a plane or a 3D space), designated by the distance and direction from the origin to that point.
If you translate the point without translating the origin, you get a position vector with a different length and/or direction.
Another kind of vector consists of the distance and direction from one point $A$ (not necessarily the origin) to another point $B$. You could visualize the vector as an arrow from $A$ to $B.$ If you then translate both $A$ and $B$ to new locations in the plane, you could imagine that the arrow is translated along with the points.
You get a new arrow which will have the same length and direction as the old one.
The thing is, mathematically, a length and direction is all that kind of vector really is. The vector doesn't have any other properties. Unlike a point, a vector doesn't actually have a position in a plane or in space. After you do your translation, you have two new points but the exact same vector.
It's like taking differences of numbers. Subtract $11$ from $13$; the answer is $2.$
Subtract $7$ from $9$; the answer is $2.$
There is only one number $2,$ but it is the difference between many different pairs of numbers. A geometric vector likewise is the difference between many different pairs of points, but it's the same vector for every one of those pairs.
So the angle between vectors of this kind is invariant under translation in a trivial way: since the vector itself is unaffected by translation, so is the angle with any other vector.
And the calculation of that angle goes exactly the same as before,
because the inputs to that calculation have not changed.

Note that the translation of points $A$ and $B$ is not a "vector space translation." It's a translation of a Euclidean space that happens to support a vector space. A "translation" of this vector space simply doesn't exist, because translation changes the location of things, and location is not a property of this kind of vector.
